# Spring SAML 2.0 behind Nginx

Tags: nginx, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I have a Spring-boot web app that uses SAML authentication provided by https://samltest.id/ .

It works fine on localhost but now I'm trying to put it on a server that has Nginx.  Ngnix is configured so that any http request is redirected to https and https://myserver.company.com/myApp/ is sent to http://local_ip:local_port/ .

This cfg works fine if the application has no security but with SAML the result is: when I access the home page of the app I'm redirected to the login page (correct) and after successful login I'm redirected to https://myserver.company.com/saml/SSO/ instead of https://myserver.company.com/myApp/saml/SSO so Nginx gives a 404.

The metadata.xml contains:

```
<md:AssertionConsumerService Location="http://myserver.company.com:80/saml/SSO"
    Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" isDefault="true" index="0"/>
<md:AssertionConsumerService Location="http://myserver.company.com:80/saml/SSO"
    Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact" index="1"/>
```

Note that URLs are **http**-based.

After a lot of Google search I have tried the following: I modified `SAMLProcessingFilter` configuration so that `filterProcessesUrl` property is `"/myApp/saml/SSO"` instead of the default value `"/saml/SSO"`.

Now the metadata.xml contains:

```
<md:AssertionConsumerService Location="http://myserver.company.com:80/myApp/saml/SSO"
    Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" isDefault="true" index="0"/>
<md:AssertionConsumerService Location="http://myserver.company.com:80/myApp/saml/SSO"
    Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact" index="1"/>
```

and after login I'm redirected to https://myserver.company.com/myApp/saml/SSO but this time I get a 404 from the web application instead of Nginx (the error page is different).

What am I missing?

### UPDATE: the 3rd attempt

- Restored `SAMLProcessingFilter` cfg to its default,
- modified the context root of my app to be http://local_ip:local_port/myApp ,
- modified Nginx cfg so that https://myserver.company.com/myApp/ maps
  to http://local_ip:local_port/myApp (same context root),
- set `entityBaseURL` property of `MetadataGenerator` to https://myserver.company.com/myApp ,
- uploaded the new metadata.xml to https://samltest.id/ (now it contains https URLs).

Now, after a successful login I'm redirected to https://myserver.company.com/myApp/saml/SSO as expected but I get a 401 from the application with message "Authentication Failed: Incoming SAML message is invalid" and in the application log there is "org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: Unsupported request".

Comment: The meta data has to reflect the URLs which the User-Agent can access. If you do a path mapping at the HTTP reverse-proxy you need adopt the SecurityConfig  to reflect this.

Comment: @BernhardThalmayr Please, explain better with a full answer.  With my 2nd attempt the metadata contains an URL that is accessible through Nginx and Nginx maps it to the usual /saml/SSO that, I supposed, is handled by my app.  I also have `http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/saml/**").permitAll()` in my Java config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several attempts I have found the solution.
No need to modify `SAMLProcessingFilter` or the context root.  The key is to use `SAMLContextProviderLB` instead of `SAMLContextProviderImpl` as described in the chapter "[Advanced configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-advanced.html)" of the manual.  Also the `entityBaseURL` change already described in my question is necessary (it is in the manual too).